# Command 'indexer' not found

Tags: linux

I have reinstalled [sphinixsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/) on Ubuntu 18.04 after some messing with maticore search. But now I can not run the indexes:

```
# indexer --all

Command 'indexer' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install sphinxsearch
```

But after reinstalling, the command does not run work either.

However I can see that the service is runing:

```
# systemctl status   sphinxsearch.service
● sphinxsearch.service - LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-03-05 13:57:48 CET; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 15615 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 15621 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 05 13:57:48 pc5 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine...
Mar 05 13:57:48 pc5 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine.
```

Interestingly the first time that installed sphinix (before removing it and installing [manticoresearch](https://manticoresearch.com/)) I could use the `indexer` command and sphinix search fine then. So I think I have removed some binaries with
`apt --purge remove sphinixsearch` or `manticoresearch` has done some damage.
In either case I'm clueless and appreciate your hints.

Comment: does it work if you give the full path to indexer?

Comment: @stark not sure what is the full path to indexer. `which indexer` gives no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved the problem by remving `sphinix` and then install it again:

```
apt remove  sphinxsearch
apt install sphinxsearch
```